# Need to Monitor CPU Fan and Have Early Warning Notification as Precaution

Tags: cpu, fan, monitoring

Does Windows have a native way of monitoring CPU fan functionality and issue early warning notification if there's something with how fan functions based on optimal threshold of fan's cycles? My fan started to make slight noises and I don't want to start experiencing downtime due to unexpected shutdowns.

Comment: How native is native? I think there's *interfaces* for it, but you'd still need something to query the fan speed and let you know.

Comment: 1) Key prerequisites: Fan RPM sensing on the mainboard (three-pin connector) and RPM sensing fan in question. 2) There are mainboard / BIOS combinations out there which monitor several temperatures and issue an early warning. 3) There are BIOSes out there which control and monitor fan speed. 4) Yes there's also user space SW, but it's hardly needed these days.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Could be even driver or service that senses when FAN's RPM are either on the low level permitted or approach critical level. Is it possible to set querying of FAN speed without software running in the background?

Comment: @ClassStacker You mean it can be done on a BIOS level? I would get a beep when FAN's RPM approach low or critical level? I am using DELL E6420 laptop.